# Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denote the *Gaussian integers*. Factor both $3+i$ and its norm into primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

> **Question**: Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denote the *Gaussian integers*.
>
> (a) Compute the norm $N(3+i)$ of $3+i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$
>
> (b) Factor both $3+i$ and its norm into primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$
>
> (c) Compute $\gcd_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}\left(3+i,2\right)$.

For (a), we have $N(3+i)=3^2+1^2=10$.

For (b), I would suspect the following to be useful

> **Proposition**: The prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are as follows:
>
> (a) $1+i$
>
> (b) the primes $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $p \equiv 3 \bmod{4}$, and
>
> (c) $a \pm bi$ where $p=a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ for the primes $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $p \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$.

However, I don't see how the above helps with factoring, for example, the norm value $10$. To me, the only logical thing to write is $10 = 2\cdot5$. Note that $5=2^2+1^2=(2+i)(2-i)$ and $5\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime with $5\equiv 1 \bmod{4}$. Therefore, by the above proposition, $(2+i)$ and $(2-i)$ are prime, and we obtain $10 = 2 \cdot (2+i) \cdot (2-i)$. But what to do about the $2$? I could write $2=(1+i)(1-i)$, but I don't believe $1-i$ is prime.

For $3+i$, I found that $3+i=(1+i)(2-i)$. Now $1+i$ is prime by (a). Since $5=2^2+1^2=(2+i)(2-i)$ and $5\in\mathbb{Z}$ is prime with $5 \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$, we have that both $(2+i)$ and $(2-i)$ are prime, in particular $(2-i)$. Therefore $(1+i)(2-i)$ factors $3+i$ into its primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

For (c), I found that $\gcd_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}\left(3+i,2\right)=-1-i$. Is this correct?

Comment: $1-i$ *is* prime, but the point is that $1-i = -i(1+i)$ so it's just a unit times the prime $1+i$ from the list.  So then, $2 = -i(1+i)^2$.  (Which leads to the question why they don't impose some restrictions in (c) to make sure that each set of associate primes has a unique representative the way they did in (a) and (b) -- for example, by requiring $a > b > 0$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Ah. So, just to be pedantic, we would say $-i$ (and $i$) is (are) prime since $1=0^2+1^2=(i)(-i)$ and $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ is prime with $1=1$ mod $4$...?

Comment: No, $i$ and $-i$ (and $-1$, 1) are not primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, they're units.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: OK. So, how do you obtain that $1-i$ is prime?

Comment: A unit times a prime is always a prime.  (But when you're working in unique factorization domains, a unit times a prime is usually viewed as not being substantially different from the original prime.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Got it, thank you.